# c# - save username from login to another form windows form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am building a system where users are logging in to my application, which is working.and i need to display the logging user name in another form with a label 
How can i do it? 
thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide some code and detail your explanation!

Comment: You didn't google enough, this is one of the basics and can be found almost everywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

> logging user name in another form with a label How can i do it

You will be needing it on multiple forms so the best solution is to keep it in a common class and read from there. Like

```
public static class CommonClass
{
  public String LoginName {get;set;}
}
```

then from your login form you can call it to set the value like

```
CommonClass.LoginName = "LoginName";
```

then you can use it anywhere you want

```
label1.Text = CommonClass.LoginName
```